# issue with date variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var dt_from = "2013/05/25";
var dt_to   = "2013/05/25";

if(dt_from == dt_to)
{
    alert("Both dates are Equal!");
}
else if(dt_from > dt_to)
{
    alert("From date should not be greater than todate!");
}
else if(dt_from < dt_to)
{
    alert("Okay!");
}
```

The above Code is working fine. But the following code is not working:

```
var dt_from = new Date("2013/05/25");
var dt_to   = new Date("2013/05/25");

if(dt_from === dt_to)
{
    alert("Both dates are Equal!");
}
else if(dt_from > dt_to)
{
    alert("From date should not be greater than todate!");
}
else if(dt_from < dt_to)
{
    alert("Okay!");
}
```

This  `if(dt_from === dt_to)` is not working with the above code. Any Idea?

Comment: Here you go sir:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing object references with `==`. While they may represent the same datetime, they are distinct objects. Using `<`/`>` works as it casts the objects to numbers (milliseconds since epoch) which are then compared. If you want to test on equality, you have to force that conversion manually:

```
dt_from.getTime() == dt_to.getTime() // most explicit
// or
+dt_from == +dt_to // shortest
dt_from - dt_to == 0  // equivalent…
dt_from.valueOf() == dt_to.valueOf()
Number(dt_from) == Number(dt_from)
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand that if we are using variable like var dt_from = "2013/05/25"; this quality comparison is working because they are value types but not if we are using var dt_from = new Date("2013/05/25"); because we are using reference types?

Comment: Exactly - strings vs. objects.

Answer (score 1):

you could compare dates using getTime(), like this:

```
var a = new Date("2013/05/25");
var b = new Date("2013/05/25");

//compare dates
alert(a.getTime() === b.getTime())
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HrJku/

Answer (score 1):

Two Dates are never **identical**, even if they refer to the same point in time.
You need to convert them to strings or numbers, 
You can subtract one from the other, for example:

```
var dt_from= new Date("2013/05/25");
var dt_to= new Date("2013/05/25");
var diff= dt_to-dt_from;


if(diff=== 0){
    alert("Both dates are Equal!");
}
else if(diff<0){
    alert("From date should not be greater than todate!");
}
else alert("Okay!");
```