# How to compare date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, compare

I want to compare following to dates i.e. d1 with d2:

```
var d1 = new Date(12,05,2013);
var d2 = "12/05/2013";
```

Comment: d1  is a date. d2 is a string.

Comment: Convert a string to a date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

Comment: `d1` is also incorrect the [spec.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) says `Date(year, month, day [, hrs, mins, secs, ms]);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare dates in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873689/issue-with-date-variable-in-javascript/16873741) or [Compare dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

convert date to timestamp

`DateObject.getTime();`  will give timestamp

and convert string to date `new Date(d2)`

**javScript**

```
var d1 = new Date("12/05/2013");
var d2 = "12/05/2013";
console.log(d1.getTime());
console.log(new Date(d2).getTime());

if(d1.getTime() == new Date(d2).getTime()){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare two variables you need to use JS operators, consider:

```
if(d1==d2)
{
 //do this
}

else
{
 //do this
}
```

More information on logical operators can be found here:  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: OP's `d1` object will never compare equal to his `d2` string like that.