# Compare DateTime by Javascript, Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datetime

I have a function which convert date to  my formatdate and compare it to CurrentDate.
It worked well when I test it with date is a date in Octorber compare to today (16/10/2013)
But if date is a date in November, the value return is true which means date < currentdate. I dont know why, anyone can explain it to me ? Thanks so much.

```
function IsPast(date) {
        var fullDate = new Date();
        var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth() + 1 + "";
        if (twoDigitMonth.length == 1) twoDigitMonth = "0" + twoDigitMonth;
        var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate() + "";
        if (twoDigitDate.length == 1) twoDigitDate = "0" + twoDigitDate;
        var currentDate = twoDigitDate + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();
        var startDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy');

        if (startDate <= currentDate) {return true;}
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can I ask you in what format do you input `date` i.e. `IsPast(10/10/2010)` ?

Comment: It's FullCalendar format of Jquery. I have checked the value after formating startDate and currentDate 01/11/2013 and 16/10/2013 but it return true :v

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697888/how-to-compare-date-in-javascript/18697997#18697997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are being passed a Date object (and that seems to be what you get), then you can simply do:

```
function isPast(date) {
  return new Date() > date;
}
```

If *date* isn't a date object, convert it to one first.

Note that identifiers starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** When I first read your question, I saw that you were using day first dates and jumped to my conclusion without really taking in your code.  I've taken a closer look, and it appears my initial conclusion is just a red herring.  **The *real* problem** is that you are taking two dates, converting them both to strings, and then trying to compare them.  That's just silly - it will only tell you which string comes first *alphabetically*.  Even sillier, is that for one of the dates you manually construct the string, but for the other one, you use a date formatting function. Why wouldn't you just use the date formatting function for both dates?

[RobG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19393898/361684) is correct and should be accepted.

---

When I see the date "01/11/2013", I read it as January 11, 2013, whereas you read it as 1 November, 2013.  See the predicament the JavaScript engine is in when it tries to parse that date?*

When parsing JavaScript dates, I like to use year first dates, as these are unambiguous as far as I know.  Everybody interprets "2013/11/01" as 2013 November 1.  Including every JavaScript Date implementation I've seen.

Change your date format to be unambiguous.

*<sup>Frankly, I'm surprised you are seeing that behavior.  I would expect that your system would be configured to expect day first dates and that the JavaScript engine would use those settings to properly parse the date.  But, I'm not *that* surprised.</sup>